# how to get tweets using twitter API in python?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm a starter in python.I use the following code to get tweets depending on a input query.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
def getData(keyword):
    url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json'
    data = {'q': keyword, 'lang': 'en', 'result_type': 'recent'}
    params = urllib.urlencode(data)
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, params)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        jsonData = json.load(response)
        tweets = []
        for item in jsonData['results']:
            tweets.append(item['text'])
        return tweets
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        self.handleError(e)
    return tweets
tweets = getData("messi")
print tweet
```

but i get the following error in the above code.
Name Error: global name 'self' is not defined. How can i correct this error?

Comment: I'm guessing you found this function online and that it was part of a class.  You could remove the `self.` and write a function called `handleError` to deal with the problem.

Comment: you should look at the `twitter` package, its on pip.

Comment: This won't work at all, because the REST API v1 is deprecated. You need to authenticate via OAuth --> Have a look at one of the Twitter-Packages, if you do not want to deal with the whole OAuth process by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Like [ChrisP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472545/how-to-get-tweets-using-twitter-api-in-python#comment32408075_21472545) said, first you need to remove `self.` from your code.
then you might get another error as handleError function is not defined anywhere in your code. So, You have to define the handleError function as well if you have not defined it yet.

Take a look at the python [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) to learn more about classes and objects.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

#defining handleError
def handleError(e):
    #Error Handling code goes here

def getData(keyword):
    url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json'
    data = {'q': keyword, 'lang': 'en', 'result_type': 'recent'}
    params = urllib.urlencode(data)
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, params)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        jsonData = json.load(response)
        tweets = []
        for item in jsonData['results']:
            tweets.append(item['text'])
        return tweets
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        handleError(e) #removed self.
    return tweets
tweets = getData("messi")
print tweet
```